# SQL query to check whether the values are same in two tables

Tags: sql

I got a table like this:

```
spsscode  spssdescription   brpcode    brpdescripton

1         cash deposit      x          cash deposit
7         withdraw          y          withdraw
8         cheque deposit    w          cheque deposit
9         bank transfer     v          bank transfer
```

here in front end of it, the input code is SPSS and it stores the information in the form of BRP CODE in database (as defined in table)

now i have got a new release where changes are not made to this table, so i have to write a query to check whether the new table in latest version is exactly same as old table or not
(i.e 1 = x, 7 = y, 8 = w, 9 = v).

in a way that i can select spss code and brp code from old table and check them against these codes in new table

Comment: What database and version are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select spsscode, spssdescription, brpcode, brpdescripton, min(which_table)
from
(select t.*, 'old' which_table from oldtable t
 union all
 select t.*, 'new' which_table from newtable t) v
group by spsscode, spssdescription, brpcode, brpdescripton
having count(*) < 2
```